# How does the jumper in Christmas lights work?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life

This is the structure  according to my textbook:
[image]

I don't know what the glass insulator are for?? But there is indeed a thin layer of insulator coating on the jumper. Why I don't know, too, what that coating is for? Can't the jumper just have a littler higher resistance to get most of the current to flow through the filament? And when the filament break, technically it will have infinite resistance, so no matter what all the current will just flow through the the jumper..

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what the glass insulator are for??

It gives mechanical support to the filament rods.  That way they don't bang into each other if the bulb is knocked around.

> Can't the jumper just have a littler higher resistance to get most of the current to flow through the filament?

No.  If it just had a "little higher resistance", then only a "little less current" would flow through it.  You would end up wasting a lot of power in those resistance loads.

Then if the filament did break, now all the current goes through the jumper.  If it had higher resistance than the bulb, then it's going to be doing a *lot* more heating.

The scheme described in the text (a burn-off insulation) allows the jumper to have high resistance (and low-current) under normal operation, and very low resistance (and low power dissipation) if the bulb burns out.

Comment: But how does that insulator coating work and look exactly? Like the conductor are soldered together

Comment: I don't know the specific material properties of the coating.  That might be a separate question.  Just that the insulation can pass some current so that if it is the only path, it is heated and burns off, leaving the low-resistance jumper available.

Comment: No but does the insulator has to cover the cross section? How?

Comment: Again, that's an implementation detail that is not shown (and not relevant to the physics).  I can *speculate* that the jumper has a coating of insulating material and is then clamped down to grab the two leads.  When the insulation is boiled off, the jumper then makes good contact with the leads.